# How to count how many times a word appears in the files in each folder?

Tags: command-line, bash, gnu

I have a directory with a lot of subdirectories with text files in them. I need to know how many times "foo" appears in every single subdirectory (but only at the first level), not the total sum of the word "foo" existing in all the subdirectories . In fewer words I would solve this by simply running manually on each directory

```
grep -riwo 'foo' | wc -l
```

Obviosly because there are a lot of them this isn't feasible. So I tried this on the directory containing the subdirectories

```
ls -1 | xargs -L1 grep -riwo 'foo' | wc -l
```

But this doesn't work also because from what I got `wc` gets the outputs only after `grep` has been executed on all the folders, piping a complete list with all the results to `wc` that simply outputs the total sum of "foo" occurring in all the directories, making `xargs` unnecessary at that point

Answer (score 1):

Since you only want totals per top-level directory, add a simple loop:

```
for d in */; do 
  printf '%s: ' "$d"; grep -riwo 'foo' -- "$d" | wc -l
done
```